# How do you represent missing value in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsnumber

What do you use to store missing value state in Core Data? Former I used NSString and stored numbers as string i.e. @"10.25". And I always converted it before any numeric calculations. And the missing value was just set with @"". But I move forward, and want to choose a primitive Numeric type to store, I can't indicate, that the value is missing. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know if this works with Core Data, but whenever I need to store a "no value" where an object is expected (e.g. a dictionary, an array, etc.), I use `[NSNull null]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an 'empty' attribute to the entry, its type is BOOL, and I just modified the logic in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an attribute as optional, and then you do not have to give it a specific value.  This is the default behavior, so you should already be able to do that.